# Trying to change the background colour of a Bootstrap 5 Button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have been trying to change the background colour of a bootstrap 5 button with some javascript. I can succesfully change the text colour from javascript, but the colour of the button is defeating me.

This is the button html code and JavaScript function called upon receiving a message from the server.

```js
function changeButtonColour(elementName) {
  const button = document.getElementById(elementName);
  if (document.getElementById(elementName).innerText === "ON") {
    button.removeAttribute("style");
    button.setAttribute("sytle", "color:red !important");
    //button.classList.remove("btn-success");
    //button.classList.add("btn-danger");
  } else {
    button.removeAttribute("style");
    button.setAttribute("sytle", "color:green !important");
    //button.classList.remove("btn-danger");
    //button.classList.add("btn-success");         
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <strong>Advance </strong>
  <a href="/heatingAdvanceButtonPressed">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
      <span id="heatingAdvanceButton">
      %HEATING_ADVANCE_BUTTON_STATE%
      </span>
    </button>
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: `setAttribute("style"`  instead of `setAttribute("sytle"`

Comment: style attributes normally don't need to be important, voting to close as it's caused by a typo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Remove and Set the button Class , like remove "btn-success" and add "btn-danger". To swap the green button to a red button

Comment: you have misspelled 'style'

Answer (score 0):

### Use CSS to set styles, then use JavaScript to toggle CSS values

While the technical implementation could vary (e.g. using `data-` attribute, `class`/`id` selectors, element selectors, etc), the core gist remains the same.

- Use CSS to create style variants (e.g. red vs green)
- Use JavaScript to target your elements, and toggle the CSS values.

See below for a very simple example.

Also, as others noted in the comment, even if you don't take this answer for your solution, make sure to spell `style` correctly.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('red');
}));
```

```css
.toggle {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle red">Click to toggle</button>

<button class="toggle">Click to toggle</button>

<button class="toggle">Click to toggle</button>

<button class="toggle red">Click to toggle</button>
```